# Is it compatible rsyslog with Logback-SLF4J?

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2, logback, spring-logback

I'm using `spring-boot-starter-web` like framework. These, use [Logback](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.8.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-logging.html#howto-configure-logback-for-logging) (without implement other libraries) to manage logs with SLF4J like a facade. I need to use it with `rsyslog` but the official doc refers only to `Syslog`.

I tried to use the `Syslog` [implementation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SyslogAppender) since `Syslog` inherit for `rsyslog` but not found ( i attach my logback-spring.xml below ).

Any idea?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds">
  <property resource="application.properties" />
   <!-- Syslog , make sure that syslog are enabled in the OS-->
     <appender name="RSYSLOG" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SyslogAppender">
        <syslogHost>127.0.0.1</syslogHost>
        <facility>LOCAL0</facility>
        <port>514</port>
        <throwableExcluded>true</throwableExcluded>
        <suffixPattern>%package.yes.rest %m thread:%t priority:%p category:%c
            exception:%exception:%msg</suffixPattern>
     </appender>

  <logger name="package.yes.rest" level="info" additivity="false">
     <appender-ref ref="RSYSLOG"/>
  </logger>
 </configuration>
```

Bonus clip: I see the [choose](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/log4j2.html) of change `Logback` to `Log4j2` too, but it's more stable use the inherit Logback.

Comment: Just a thought.  If the SyslogAppender isn't going to work, there could very well be a third party Appender out in the wild that would support rsyslog.  In fact, if you could go with either Logbck or Log4j, I'd find it really strange if you couldn't find support for rsyslog for at least one of those frameworks.

Comment: The question is if it's possible doing with Logback, no if LOG4J2 can do it.